# Why is Python Popen using a different executable

Tags: python, path, subprocess, popen

I have a program with two different versions on this computer.  I can't get rid of the older one because I don't have root access, but I put the newer one first in 'bin' in my home directory (which is the first thing in my $PATH)

I tried calling it with Python's Popen

```
Popen(['clingo'...]...)
```

and it worked fine

But then I needed to set an environment variable before calling it so I renamed 'clingo' to 'run_clingo' in the bin directory and replaced it with a script:

```
# File: ~/bin/clingo
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc4.8.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
run_clingo $@
```

When I run 'clingo' from terminal, it works fine, but Python Popen calls the older version (which is later on the PATH).

How can I get Popen to call the right one?  Why does changing an executable to a script cause Popen to search elsewhere?

Comment: Is your script in fact missing its shebang? If so, how is the system to know what executable is needed to run it?

Comment: My script has no shebang.  What should I put there? Why?

Comment: You can set environment variables in the `Popen()` call via the `env=` keyword argument.

Comment: unrelated: you probably want `"$@"` instead `$@`.

Comment: You need shebang for the Python script if you want to run it as executable.  If there's none, OS will assume it's shell script and run it using what the user has in /etc/passwd.  Shebang has no effect if you run the script by calling `python path/to/script`.  Your question does not seem like problem is there, though, since in that case your script would probably fail completely and strangely, not "call the older version".

Comment: @AloisMahdal: incorrect. If you remove the shebang from `~/bin/clingo` then `Popen('clingo')` picks up the second executable, not from `~/bin`. It doesn't use `/etc/passwd` on my system (Ubuntu).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian that's strange.  If an *executable* script (or an ELF, for that matter) is found on PATH, there's no reason to look further, no matter shebang; it should be executed.  Now if it's not ELF but plaintext, shell is assumed.  Shebang can override the assumption but if it's missing, then the mere fact that the text is in Python/Perl/Java/English should normally result in syntax error ... but not in another PATH lookup.  *Now if Popen behaves differently then I'm even more scared of it.* ;)

Comment: @AloisMahdal: It is the first time, I've heard about inspecting `/etc/passwd` on `ENOEXEC`. You might be talking about the behaviour for [`exec*p()` functions that since POSIX.1-2008 require to run `sh` on `ENOEXEC`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html). There is a [Python bug about `os.exec*p()` differing in behaviour from POSIX](http://bugs.python.org/issue19948). It might be worth opening a separate bug specifically for Popen.

Comment: Should I try setting shell=True?  What does shell=True mean?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You're right, I was completely wrong with the /etc/passwd, I was just thinking it works that way all the time, I don't even know where I got that.  Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian And embarrassingly enough, I was wrong also in the other part.  Yes, it's the bug you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Add shebang `#!/bin/sh` at the very top of `~/bin/clingo` and run:

```
$ chmod +x ~/bin/clingo
```

to make the file executable.

`Popen()` calls `os.execvp()` to execute a program. [Its behaviour differs from your shell that emulates `execvp()`](http://bugs.python.org/issue19948): if there is no the shebang (`!#..` at the top) in the script then the shell reruns it as a shell script but Python's `os.execvp()` runs the next file in PATH instead.

Comment: @dspyz: what happens if you call `subprocess.check_call([os.path.expanduser("~/bin/clingo)])`

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess is that Popen does not use the same PATH as your terminal.  I would check the shebang line (`#!`) sometimes people put `env -i python` there, which explicitly asks fro empty, i.e. default environment.

Note that `subprocess.call` is the recommended way, not using the `Popen` directly.

Comment: No, it's using the same path.  I tried adding env -i python and it didn't change anything.  Also, if that were the case, it wouldn't explain why it works when I call the executable directly (as opposed to calling a script).  I need to use Popen rather than call because I need to pass to p.stdin  I tried printing out the path os.environ['PATH'] just to check and it is the same

Comment: `call` in essence is just `Popen().wait()` i.e., neither is "better" (or more recommended) than the other. It depends on your needs what to use.

Comment: I was referring to the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module): *The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the following convenience functions for all use cases they can handle.* ... how "much recommended" you consider that depends on you :)

Comment: *"for all use cases they can handle"*

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian ...and since I don't know what the use case is or why exactly OP wants to launch the program from Python script in the first place, I add the note to remind of the convenience functions.

Comment: @Alois Mahdal: it is ok to remind about the convenience functions. It is not ok to recommend them *unconditionally* without any regard for a use case.